# Why isn't Filter A on Top Z on Top not working?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, filter, task-list

[image: Photo of filter for task List]

I am using SharePoint 2013. Within a Task List I want to use the filter A on Top Z on Top. However, it's not changing the titles of the Tasks. Is this something from the Administrator Permission's end or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are filtering the wrong column. from your image what i am seeing you are filtering the Completed column which has two values ( Yes and No).  You are seeing the Only NO because no task is completed yet. If you click on the checkbox on the task then you will see Yes.

Hover the Mouse on the TaskName and then click on dropdown. now you will see all the tasks, Click on the filter which you want `A to z Ascending` or `Z to A Descending`.

Comment: However, I still don't know why it doesn't put the Z on top after I selected my Task that starts with Z and a task that starts with C.

Comment: Because the sort isn't on the task name column, your sort is on the task status column as Waqas mentioned.